# How to have google index a login protected url?

Tags: google, security, search-engine-indexing

For example, my site:
`http://abcde.foobar.com` is protected by a "single sign on" login page hosted at `http://sso.foobar.com`, so when a user visits "abcde", they get redirected to the "sso" login page always, and they have to login to access "abcde".

It seems Google does not know about my "abcde" site at all, how do I make google know about my "abcde" site? Because a lot of my users are trying to search for "abcde" in google and the site doesn't come up. (my "abcde" url is very obsecure and not a word, so google should put my site on top if it had known about it)

Answer (score 2):

According to this blog post on the Official Google Webmaster Center Blog http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2008/10/first-click-free-for-web-search.html

It's possible to give Google access to protected content to crawl.

Comment: I was reading about this the other day, its how the NY Times site is index even though they have a paywall

Answer (score 0):

You need to have some publicly available content at `abcde.foobar.com` for Google to index it. "abcde" should also appear in the page content of those pages if you want to rank for that term - not solely in the URL. The URL is just a (small) factor in determining relevance.

Comment: And to suggest an approach to achieving that you might create a page on abcde.foobar.com which has the content you wish to be found for (a landing page of sorts). From this you could redirect the user back to the single sign-on site for login, from which they can then get redirected back to the protected content on abcde.foobar.com.

Comment: ok thanks I'm testing this out right now, hope this works.